# how to concatenate multi column cell data with quotations and commas

Tags: csv, concatenation, delimiter, textjoin

I had 50 columns of data from "G" to "BD" with record data organized in rows. Some cells had data, some did not. I wanted to find a way to concatenate any of the data from the columns in each row within quotation marks, and separated (delimited) by commas. I found the easiest way to do this was test if the row was not blank; if true, then start the output with a quotation CHAR(34), use textjoin to find and join any others found, and then end with another quotation.

```
=IF(TEXTJOIN(""",""",TRUE,G3:BD3)<>"",CHAR(34)&(TEXTJOIN(""",""",TRUE,G3:BD3)&CHAR(34)),"")
```

I hope this helps if anyone else needs a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

=IF(TEXTJOIN(""",""",TRUE,G3:BD3)<>"",CHAR(34)&(TEXTJOIN(""",""",TRUE,G3:BD3)&CHAR(34)),"")

I hope this helps if anyone else needs a solution to this problem.